# Subversion edge on windows 7 ldap_simple_bind_s failed

Tags: svn, ldap, tortoisesvn

I'm using TortoiseSVN to connect to my subversionedge server for source control.

This has been working all along until one of our main switches got reset and changed the IP address of a few of our servers. Long story short, I have changed back all the IP to its original address, but I don't know why this affected the connection to the subversionedge svn server.

I now get this error when I try to connect to my repository from tortoiseSVN

Unable to connect to a repository at URL  Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Server Error) in response to OPTIONS request for

Here are the server logs

```
[Sat Mar 16 23:38:09 2013] [info] [client 192.168.168.72] Connection closed to child 63 with standard shutdown (server ASIS-NVR.sharepoint.com:443)
[Sat Mar 16 23:38:09 2013] [info] [client 192.168.168.72] Connection to child 63 established (server ASIS-NVR.sharepoint.com:443)
[Sat Mar 16 23:38:09 2013] [info] Seeding PRNG with 144 bytes of entropy
[Sat Mar 16 23:38:09 2013] [info] Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 63 (server ASIS-NVR.sharepoint.com:443)
[Sat Mar 16 23:38:09 2013] [info] Subsequent (No.2) HTTPS request received for child 63 (server ASIS-NVR.sharepoint.com:443)
[Sat Mar 16 23:38:09 2013] [info] [client 192.168.168.72] [7508] auth_ldap authenticate: user pyae authentication failed; URI /svn/Software [LDAP: ldap_simple_bind_s() failed][Server Down]
[Sat Mar 16 23:38:09 2013] [info] [client 192.168.168.72] Connection closed to child 63 with standard shutdown (server ASIS-NVR.sharepoint.com:443)
[Sat Mar 16 23:38:10 2013] [info] [client 192.168.168.72] Connection to child 63 established (server ASIS-NVR.sharepoint.com:443)
[Sat Mar 16 23:38:10 2013] [info] Seeding PRNG with 144 bytes of entropy
[Sat Mar 16 23:38:10 2013] [info] Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 63 (server ASIS-NVR.sharepoint.com:443)
[Sat Mar 16 23:38:10 2013] [info] [client 192.168.168.72] Connection to child 62 established (server ASIS-NVR.sharepoint.com:443)
[Sat Mar 16 23:38:10 2013] [info] Seeding PRNG with 144 bytes of entropy
[Sat Mar 16 23:38:10 2013] [info] Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 62 (server ASIS-NVR.sharepoint.com:443)
[Sat Mar 16 23:38:10 2013] [info] [client 192.168.168.72] Connection closed to child 62 with standard shutdown (server ASIS-NVR.sharepoint.com:443)
[Sat Mar 16 23:38:10 2013] [info] [client 192.168.168.72] Connection closed to child 63 with standard shutdown (server ASIS-NVR.sharepoint.com:443)


<Location /svn/>   
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath "F:/csvn/data/repositories"
   SVNReposName "CollabNet Subversion Repository"
  AuthzSVNAccessFile "F:\csvn\data/conf/svn_access_file"
  SVNListParentPath On
  Allow from all
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "CollabNet Subversion Repository"
  AuthBasicProvider  ldap-users
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Comment: Um, check the LDAP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant error is this one:

```
auth_ldap authenticate: user pyae authentication failed; URI /svn/Software [LDAP: ldap_simple_bind_s() failed][Server Down]
```

Either it cannot reach the LDAP server, or the credentials provided for the BindDN are no longer valid.